# Github does not display all the folders, sub-folders, and files

Tags: git, github, repository

I added all my folders and its sub-contents into my local repository. I used all of the following:

```
git add .
git add -A
git add -all
git add *
```

After using git add, I used git commit -a to commit all my files. Following all these steps, I use git remote and git push to add the contents into my Github repository. However, when I go on my Github repository, only the folders are displayed but there is no content or subfolders. How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Are the empty folders shown with a grey icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `git commit -m "some message"`.

`git commit -a` stages only files that are deleted or modified, but not new files.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Answer (score 0):

`git add .` or `git add -A` will stage all the files/folders. Once you commit these changes you should see them with 'git show' in your local repo.
And for remote repo Make sure `.gitignore` doesn't ignore these file extentions

Answer (score 0):

```
git add .
```

adds all the files into staging and you need to commit your changes using below command.

```
git commit -m 'commit message'
```

then only it will we appeared in the github when you use the command

```
git push
```

And other thing is git doesn't track empty directories. You can make an empty commit with `git commit --allow-empty` , but that will not allow you to commit an empty folder structure as git does not know or care about folders as objects themselves -- just the files they contain.